# How to paraphrase: "key questions include"?

Tags: lists, paraphrasing

I’m not a native English speaker and it seems I can’t find enough suitable and different phrases for introducing lists. I’m writing an abstract for a scientific conference and would like to avoid word repetition in such a short text. I used the phrases “Preferred topics include ...” and “Key questions include: ...”. Do you have any suggestions to preserve the original (or close) meaning of the phrases without repeating the word *include*?

Comment: You could drop the word "include" from these headings and just include a bullet-point list of topics, questions etc. below the headings of "Preferred Topics", "Key Questions" and any others...

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but in humanities, for the purpose of the conference, it is more or less expected to write in full sentences.

Comment: Do you mean you've already used the phrases "Preferred topics include" and ""Key questions include" and you want to say the same thing a third time without using the same words? If this is just a short abstract then why are you saying the same thing so many times?

Comment: No, I initially wrote those 2 phrases and would like to change one of them.

Comment: Important topics, main issues, areas of concern, items to consider...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some key topics are...

Key topics are...

Key topics contain...

Key topics not restricted to...

Key topics can encompass...

Key topics range from ... to ...

Comment: Thank you, I was not sure if the word encompass in this context is correct.

Comment: The problem is that by using the word "include" you are saying that you are only listing *some* of the items and not all possible items. If that is the case then it is difficult to find synonyms for *include*. Encompasses may only be partially relevant but is a way to define that the list that follows is not exhaustive. You probably do mean to include an exhaustive list (why list only *some* of the key topics?) and so "include" and its synonyms is not a good choice of word and you should use "Preferred Topics are..." and "Key Questions are..."

Comment: Actually it's not a paper, but a panel, and I would like to allow/encourage people to include topics and questions I don't list in proposal. That's why I have a hard time finding a synonim for "include".

Comment: Ah right, okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

> Key questions are ... .

or

> Key questions consist of ... .

or

> A, B, C are among the key questions ... .

Comment: Thank you. I guess I could also use: Prefferd topics encompass ... and then Key questions include ..., right?

Comment: Yeah, you can I suppose. I didn't add *encompass* as I felt it's not so common; but it's totally correct.

Comment: I like "A, B, C are among the key questions ..." more

Comment: @ŽivaEnder No problem. Just don't forget to *upvote* the answers that helped you by clicking the up arrow on the left of each answer; and accept the most helpful answer by clicking on the check mark under the arrows.